# ModelInstance rotation animation

Tags: animation, 3d, rotation, libgdx

I have a model that i need to animate, i need to rotate it from 0 to 45 degrees on an axis in duration of 2 seconds, is there a easier way to do it, now i just create a timer with a boolean to switch the animation off

```
Timer.schedule(new Task() {
     @Override
     public void run() {
     stopAnim = true;
     }
     }, 2);
```

and in the render method

```
if (stopAnim = false){
        bodyModelInstance.transform.rotate(Vector3.Y, 40 * delta);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the perfect thing for you would be [Universal Tween Engine](http://www.aurelienribon.com/blog/projects/universal-tween-engine/).

It's easy, and you can create complex animations easily with less code and in less time.

Hope this helps.
Good luck.